# Really simple short string compression

Tags: c#, string, compression, short

Is there a really simple compression technique for strings up to about 255 characters in length (yes, I'm compressing [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator))?

I am not concerned with the strength of compression - I am looking for something that performs very well and is quick to implement. I would like something simpler than [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/): something that can be implemented with a couple of short methods.

Comment: Why? There is probably a better way to do what you're asking.

Comment: "Why" is certainly a good answer. However, as a side note, Huffman coding works great for simple text compression without having to resort to external libraries and LZW compression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best compression algorithm for short text strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138345/best-compression-algorithm-for-short-text-strings)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the key question here is "*Why do you want to compress URLs?*"

**Trying to shorten long urls for the address bar?**

You're better storing the original URL somewhere (database, text file ...) alongside a hashcode of the non-domain part (MD5 is fine).  You can then have a simple page (or some HTTPModule if you're feeling flashy) to read the MD5 and lookup the real URL.  This is how TinyURL and others work.

For example:

```
http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/page1.aspx
```

Could be shorted to:

```
http://mydomain.com/2d4f1c8a
```

*Using a compression library for this will not work*.  The string will be compressed into a shorter binary representation, but converting this back to a string which needs to be valid as part of a URL (e.g. Base64) will negate any benefit you gained from the compression.

**Storing lots of URLs in memory or on disk?**

Use the built in compressing library within System.IO.Compression or the ZLib library which is simple and incredibly good.  Since you will be storing binary data the compressed output will be fine as-is.  You'll need to uncompress it to use it as a URL.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.  What if you have nowhere to store the hashtable?

Comment: @endolith - The point is string compression will not help you here, only relating it to a hash or similar.  See Cheeso's answer for real world example compressions longer and just as long in the original when converted back to valid URLs.  You always have "somewhere" to store a hash.  Hard code it into your URL redirection code if you really do have "nowhere" to store it!

Comment: You don't always have somewhere to store a hashtable, and it doesn't always make the URL longer.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme, for instance

Comment: Data uri is not any sort of compression, and had nothing to do with shortening urls. In fact data uri is for embedding data in web pages and uses base64, which if you read chesso's answer you will see is much longer. In which case would you not have somewhere to store url/hash code references? If you have a form of compression which will shorten a URL and still be a valid URL please post it as an answer, I'm sure the community will benefit.

Answer (score 12):

As suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192732/really-simple-short-string-compression-c/1192853#1192853), Using data compression does not work to shorten URL paths that are already fairly short.

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) has a DeflateStream class that exposes a static (Shared in VB) [CompressString](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/b1d910c8-a036-dc5d-321e-c2d63e724130.htm) method.  It's a one-line way to compress a string using DEFLATE ([RFC 1951](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)).  The DEFLATE implementation is fully compatible with [System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx), but DotNetZip compresses better. Here's how you might use it:

```
string[] orig = {
    "folder1/folder2/page1.aspx",
    "folderBB/folderAA/page2.aspx",
};
public void Run()
{
    foreach (string s in orig)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("original    : {0}", s);
        byte[] compressed = DeflateStream.CompressString(s);
        System.Console.WriteLine("compressed  : {0}", ByteArrayToHexString(compressed));
        string uncompressed = DeflateStream.UncompressString(compressed);
        System.Console.WriteLine("uncompressed: {0}\n", uncompressed);
    }
}
```

Using that code, here are my test results:

```
original    : folder1/folder2/page1.aspx
compressed  : 4bcbcf49492d32d44f03d346fa0589e9a9867a89c5051500
uncompressed: folder1/folder2/page1.aspx

original    : folderBB/folderAA/page2.aspx
compressed  : 4bcbcf49492d7272d24f03331c1df50b12d3538df4128b0b2a00
uncompressed: folderBB/folderAA/page2.aspx
```

So you can see the "compressed" byte array, when represented in hex, is longer than the original, about 2x as long. The reason is that a hex byte is actually 2 ASCII chars.

You could compensate somewhat for that by using base-62, instead of base-16 (hex) to represent the number. In that case a-z and A-Z are also digits, giving you 0-9 (10) + a-z (+26) + A-Z (+26) = 62 total digits.  That would shorten the output significantly.  I haven't tried that. yet.

---

**EDIT**
Ok I tested the Base-62 encoder.  It shortens the hex string by about half.  I figured it would cut it to 25% (62/16 =~ 4) But I think I am losing something with the discretization.   In my tests, the resulting base-62 encoded string is about the same length as the original URL.  So, no, using compression and then base-62 encoding is still not a good approach.  you really want a hash value.

Comment: Using hex is pretty stupid, it's not a dense format at all. Using base64 or even base85 and replacing the invalid characters by correct ones (escaping again takes space) will certainly reduce the output. Not as much as you are claiming though, your math is off. Of course, the shorter the URI's, the less compression you can expect, and it also matters what the context is.

Comment: The conclusion of this answer ("using compression then .... is still not a good approach") is no longer valid - see my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50751602/887092

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest looking in the [System.IO.Compression Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx). There's [an article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/GZipStream.aspx) that may help.

Answer (score 3):

I have just created a compression scheme that targets URLs and achieves around 50% compression (compared to base64 representation of the original URL text).

see http://blog.alivate.com.au/packed-url/

---

It would be great if someone from a big tech company built this out properly and published it for all to use. Google championed Protocol buffers. This tool can save a lot of disk space for someone like Google, while still being scannable. Or perhaps the great captain himself? https://twitter.com/capnproto

Technically, I would call this a binary (bitwise) serialisation scheme for the data that underlies a URL. Treat the URL as text-representation of conceptual data, then serialize that conceptual data model with a specialised serializer. The outcome is a more compressed version of the original of course. This is very different to how a general-purpose compression algorithm works.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Do you have any example code or a project you could share?  I couldn't find anything on the site you linked.

Comment: I do have some code I can dig up. Please leave a comment on my blog and we can connect that way.

Comment: Did you manage to dig it up?

Answer (score 1):

What's your goal?

- A shorter URL? Try URL shorteners like http://tinyurl.com/ or http://is.gd/
- Storage space? Check out System.IO.Compression. (Or [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/))

Comment: Not concerned with strength of compression - I am looking for something that performs very well and is quick to implement. Can you point me to base64?

Comment: Base64 is not going to compress anything :)

Comment: @Jon Grant: Correct. Base64 was a stupid suggestion. Would only work after actually compressing to get something that (perhaps) is smaller, but still ascii. Have removed all trace of the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use deflate algorithm directly, without any headers checksums or footers, as described in this question: [Python: Inflate and Deflate implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089662/python-inflate-and-deflate-implementations)

This cuts down a 4100 character URL to 1270 base64 characters, in my test, allowing it to fit inside IE's 2000 limit.

And here's an example of a [4000-character URL](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+3+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+50%0AL+272+32+272+8+2+0+false+5.0+0.0%0AL+320+32+320+8+2+1+false+5.0+0.0%0AL+368+32+368+8+2+0+false+5.0+0.0%0AL+416+32+416+8+2+1+false+5.0+0.0%0AI+272+32+272+80+0+0.5%0AI+320+32+320+80+0+0.5%0AI+368+32+368+80+0+0.5%0AI+416+32+416+80+0+0.5%0Aw+320+32+344+32+0%0Aw+344+32+344+96+0%0A151+72+168+72+216+1+4+5.0%0A151+128+168+128+216+1+3+5.0%0A151+184+168+184+216+1+2+5.0%0A151+240+168+240+216+1+4+5.0%0A151+600+168+600+216+1+3+5.0%0A151+552+168+552+216+1+3+0.0%0A151+504+168+504+216+1+3+5.0%0A151+456+168+456+216+1+3+5.0%0A151+400+168+400+216+1+3+5.0%0A150+304+168+304+216+1+2+0.0%0A152+352+168+352+216+1+2+5.0%0Aw+344+96+120+96+0%0Aw+120+96+120+168+0%0Aw+344+96+512+96+0%0Aw+512+96+560+96+0%0Aw+560+96+608+96+0%0Aw+608+96+608+168+0%0Aw+560+168+560+96+0%0Aw+512+168+512+96+0%0Aw+368+32+392+32+0%0Aw+392+32+392+104+0%0Aw+192+168+192+104+0%0Aw+128+168+128+104+0%0Aw+128+104+192+104+0%0Aw+192+104+392+104+0%0Aw+392+104+456+104+0%0Aw+456+104+456+168+0%0Aw+456+104+600+104+0%0Aw+600+104+600+168+0%0Aw+416+32+440+32+0%0Aw+440+32+440+112+0%0Aw+440+112+552+112+0%0Aw+552+112+552+168+0%0Aw+440+112+408+112+0%0Aw+408+168+408+112+0%0Aw+408+112+256+112+0%0Aw+256+112+256+168+0%0Aw+256+112+136+112+0%0Aw+136+112+136+168+0%0Aw+272+80+272+120+0%0Aw+272+120+248+120+0%0Aw+248+120+248+168+0%0Aw+248+120+56+120+0%0Aw+56+120+56+168+0%0Aw+272+120+360+120+0%0Aw+360+120+360+168+0%0Aw+320+80+320+128+0%0Aw+312+168+312+128+0%0Aw+312+128+320+128+0%0Aw+232+168+232+128+0%0Aw+312+128+232+128+0%0Aw+232+128+176+128+0%0Aw+176+128+176+168+0%0Aw+176+128+64+128+0%0Aw+64+128+64+168+0%0Aw+320+128+392+128+0%0Aw+392+128+392+168+0%0Aw+392+128+464+128+0%0Aw+464+128+464+168+0%0Aw+368+80+368+136+0%0Aw+368+136+400+136+0%0Aw+400+136+400+168+0%0Aw+400+136+504+136+0%0Aw+504+136+504+168+0%0Aw+368+136+296+136+0%0Aw+296+136+296+168+0%0Aw+296+136+224+136+0%0Aw+224+136+224+168+0%0Aw+224+136+80+136+0%0Aw+80+136+80+168+0%0Aw+416+80+416+144+0%0Aw+504+136+544+136+0%0Aw+544+136+544+168+0%0Aw+416+144+448+144+0%0Aw+448+144+448+168+0%0Aw+448+144+496+144+0%0Aw+496+144+496+168+0%0Aw+496+144+592+144+0%0Aw+592+144+592+168+0%0Aw+416+144+272+144+0%0Aw+272+144+88+144+0%0Aw+88+144+88+168+0%0Aw+304+216+328+216+0%0Aw+328+216+328+168+0%0Aw+328+168+344+168+0%0A150+88+280+88+328+1+4+5.0%0A150+264+280+264+328+1+4+5.0%0A150+416+280+416+328+1+4+5.0%0A150+368+280+368+328+1+3+0.0%0A150+320+280+320+328+1+2+5.0%0A150+208+280+208+328+1+3+0.0%0A150+152+280+152+328+1+4+5.0%0Aw+72+216+72+280+0%0Aw+272+144+272+224+0%0Aw+272+224+200+224+0%0Aw+200+224+200+280+0%0Aw+208+280+208+232+0%0Aw+208+232+272+232+0%0Aw+272+232+272+280+0%0Aw+272+232+432+232+0%0Aw+432+232+432+280+0%0Aw+432+232+504+232+0%0Aw+504+232+504+216+0%0Aw+216+280+216+248+0%0Aw+216+248+160+248+0%0Aw+160+248+160+280+0%0Aw+160+248+96+248+0%0Aw+96+248+96+280+0%0Aw+80+280+80+240+0%0Aw+104+280+104+256+0%0Aw+104+256+168+256+0%0Aw+168+256+168+280+0%0Aw+80+240+128+240+0%0Aw+128+240+128+216+0%0Aw+128+240+144+240+0%0Aw+144+240+144+280+0%0Aw+184+216+184+224+0%0Aw+184+224+136+224+0%0Aw+136+224+136+280+0%0Aw+424+280+424+240+0%0Aw+424+240+376+240+0%0Aw+376+240+376+280+0%0Aw+424+240+600+240+0%0Aw+600+240+600+216+0%0Aw+144+240+256+240+0%0Aw+256+240+256+280+0%0Aw+216+248+248+248+0%0Aw+248+248+248+280+0%0Aw+240+216+240+256+0%0Aw+168+256+240+256+0%0Aw+240+256+400+256+0%0Aw+400+256+400+280+0%0Aw+408+280+408+248+0%0Aw+408+248+360+248+0%0Aw+360+248+360+280+0%0Aw+360+248+312+248+0%0Aw+312+248+312+280+0%0Aw+352+216+360+216+0%0Aw+360+216+360+248+0%0Aw+312+248+248+248+0%0Aw+280+280+280+224+0%0Aw+280+224+400+224+0%0Aw+400+224+400+216+0%0Aw+328+280+328+264+0%0Aw+328+264+456+264+0%0Aw+456+264+456+216+0%0Aw+368+280+368+272+0%0Aw+368+272+552+272+0%0Aw+552+272+552+216+0%0A157+464+312+584+312+0%0Aw+464+312+448+312+0%0Aw+448+312+448+328+0%0Aw+448+328+416+328+0%0Aw+464+344+368+344+0%0Aw+368+344+368+328+0%0Aw+464+376+320+376+0%0Aw+320+376+320+328+0%0Aw+464+408+264+408+0%0Aw+264+408+264+328+0%0Aw+528+440+208+440+0%0Aw+208+440+208+328+0%0Aw+560+440+560+448+0%0Aw+560+448+152+448+0%0Aw+152+448+152+328+0%0Aw+592+440+592+456+0%0Aw+592+456+88+456+0%0Aw+88+456+88+328+0%0A), which can't be solved with a hashtable since the applet can exist on any server.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with trying one of the existing (free or open source) zip libraries, e.g. http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Zip should work well for text strings, and I am not sure if it is worth implementing a compression algorithm yourserlf....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/)?

No idea if it would work effectively with such short strings, but I'd say its probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The open source library [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) is easy to use and will provide you with compression tools