# long NSString to unique shorter string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a long NSString like that;

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"st=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&max=10"];
```

It is too long and i should make it shorter. It must me unique with its original string. 
Any idea?

Thanks;

Comment: What is your string for?

Comment: How do you generate that string or is it fixed ?

Comment: it is a url to get some data. and i'll use this parameter string to generate cache file. beacuse it is too long, ios do not let me to use it as a file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this blog is a good solution of my question.

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html

Comment: MD5 hashes created from a string are not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to retrieve the string later, you can hash it with, for example, SHA1 (have a look at Apple's CommonCrypto library).

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with iphone or objective c, but this seems like you could use something like a hashmap or a dictionary - *value* being the shortened string (cache file name), or whatever, and *key* being your long url. I guess there's some data structure available in objective c/iOS for this purposes...
Also, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192732/really-simple-short-string-compression).
It might not be a good idea to use really long strings for dictionary keys, it's usually the other way around: keys are short, value holds arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

There are some wrapper classes used for shortening URLs like MKBitlyHelper.Using this class you can shorten your url and then use it further.You can get it from here  http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/bit-ly-wrapper-objective-c-iphone/