# Wrong ELF class - Python

Tags: javascript, python, compression, libraries, lzw

I'm trying to install this library for **LZJB** compression. [PyLZJB LINK](http://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/)

The library is a binding for a C library, the file is located here [PyLZJB.so](http://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/downloads/detail?name=PyLZJB.so&can=2&q=)

---

Unfortunately by copying to the site-packages directory when import I get the **"Wrong ELF class" error**.

```
>>> import PyLZJB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./PyLZJB.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

---

**Help would be great.** :)

PS: I'm running Ubuntu 10.4 **64bit**

---

## Edit:

**If someone could suggest me an alternative compression algorithm I would be equally happy. :)**

The algorithm is for **HTML compression**, and it needs client side **Javascript decompression/compression support too**.

I really hope someone can help on this one. Thanks guys!

Comment: Ick, decompression in JavaScript? You can't take advantage of the built-in compression support in most modern browsers and HTTP servers?

Comment: @Nicholas – I totally agree: decompression in JavaScript, which is essentially an interpreted language, will be very slow in comparison to a browser's (or operating system's) native (GZip) compression. @RadiantHex – Just curious: why do you need this?

Comment: @Nicholas: do they Gzip GET parameters within a request?

Comment: @Marcel: I'm sending loads of debugging data from and to a server... and I really need to compress this. Also compression is an easy way to serialize data too for a GET request, don't you think? :)

Comment: @RadiantHex: If you're putting enough data in GET parameters to justify compression, there's almost certainly something very wrong with your application design. I would strongly suggest posting a new question asking for advice on how to accomplish what you're doing in a saner manner.

Comment: @Nicholas: The data I'm sending out is already minimized quite a lot. It's actually not a lot of data, I just wanted to use LZJB compression as it is very fast on the client-side. Even manages to achieve 30% ratio at times.

Comment: Have you considered `zlib`? This should work, and it's a fairly standard compression format. `zlib` allows you to compress an arbitrary string, while `gzip` module uses `zlib` to create `.gz` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If someone could suggest me an alternative compression algorithm I would be equally happy.

There is always good old deflate, a much more common member of the LZ compression family. [JavaScript implementation](http://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate). [How to handle raw deflate content with Python's zlib module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089662/python-inflate-and-deflate-implementations).

This a lot of overhead in relatively slow client-side code to be compressing submission data, and it's not trivial to submit the raw bytes you will obtain from it.

> do they Gzip GET parameters within a request?

GET form submissions in the query string must by nature be fairly short, or you will overrun browser or server URL length limits. There is no point compressing anything so small. If you have a lot of data, it needs to go in a POST form.

Even in a POST form, the default `enctype` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which means a majority of bytes are going to get encoded as `%nn` sequences. This will balloon your form submission, probably beyond the original uncompressed size. To submit raw bytes you would have to use a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` form.

Even then, you're going to have encoding problems. JS strings are Unicode not bytes, and will get encoded using the encoding of the page containing the form. That should normally be UTF-8, but then you can't actually generate an arbitrary sequence of bytes for upload by encoding to it, since many byte sequences are not valid in UTF-8. You could have bytes-in-unicode by encoding each byte as a code unit to UTF-8, but that would bloat your compressed bytes by 50% (since half the code units, those over `0x80`, would encode to two UTF-8 bytes).

In theory, if you didn't mind losing proper internationalisation support, you could serve the page as ISO-8859-1 and use the `escape/encodeURIComponent` idiom to convert between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 for output. But that won't work because browsers lie and actually use Windows code page 1252 for encoding/decoding content marked as ISO-8859-1. You could use another encoding that mapped every byte to a character, but that'd be more manual encoding overhead and would further limit characters you could use in the page.

You could avoid encoding problems by using something like base64, but then, again, you've got more manual encoding performance overhead and a 33% bloat.

In summary, all approaches are bad; I don't think you're going to get much useful out of this.

Answer (score 7):

You are running a 64 bit Python interpreter and trying to load a 32 bit extension and that is not allowed.

You need to have both your Python interpreter and your extension compiled for the same architectures.  While you could get a 32 bit Python interpreter, it would probably be better to get a 64 bit extension.

What you should do is get the source for [LZJB](http://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/source/checkout) and build it yourself to get a 64 bit shared object.

Comment: @Samuel: thanks for the reply! I'm a bit confused on how to build it though, could you give me a few pointers please? :)

Comment: @RadiantHex, if the package uses `distutils`, it's usually as simple as running setup.py with your 64-bit python runtime. Sometimes, you need to resort to specifying `CFLAGS=--march=x86_64` and `CXXFLAGS=--march=x86_64` in your environment, depending on how the native code is built. This assumes AMD x64 architecture, you may need a different flag if you're on Intel.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run a 32-bit Python or compile your own PyLZJB rather than using the prebuilt binary.  Or get a 64-bit binary PyLZJB from somewhere.