# Python 2.7 cant decode deflate encoding

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, gzip, urllib, zlib

For some reason urllib is corrupting documents that i download from a website. The url is definitely correct. The documents download with their correct names but they appear corrupted once opened. I found that the download is encoded with deflate so i attempted to decode it but i keep getting either these two errors when i modify the "zlib" part.

errors:

```
error-2 while preparing to decompress data: inconsistent stream state
```

or

```
error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

here is a code snippet of where the problem is:

```
def download_file(url, name):
try:
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
fh = open(name, 'wb')
if f.info().get('content-encoding') == 'deflate':
 fh = zlib.decompress(f.read(),16 +zlib.MAX_WBITS)
#fh.write(f.read())
fh.close()
print "  File Downloaded : " , name

except Exception:
    raise
```

Comment: `gzip` and `deflate` are treated differently when decompressing.

Comment: See [Python: Inflate and Deflate implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1089662) for deflate code.

Comment: I've said this in a previous comment but I'll reiterate it here: use the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead, it handles decompression transparently for you.

Comment: How comes your code snippet has an `except` without a `try`?

Comment: could you give me an example with my code above using the requests library to decode deflate?

Comment: @tobias_k sorry i missed that bit out, i added it now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you give me an example with my code above using the requests library to decode deflate?

Comment: @RitchieRamnial: you don't need to do anything; accessing the response body via `.content` or `.text` gives you the decompressed content. If you want to download to a file object (streaming) and want to use the raw socket, you can set a flag to have it decompress as you read as well. See [How to download image using requests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13137817)

Comment: @MartijnPieters i still cant get it to work. the aim is to download the file from the link. the file that downloads is still encoded and unreadable. please could you dumb it down for me and show me an example with my code?

Comment: @RitchieRamnial: the code in the other answer *is* the sample I'd give. If that doesn't produce non-corrupted results, the server is not giving you the headers the client needs to decode the information. You'd have to manually deflate / unzip, for which there are already answers here on SO that tell you how.

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you link me to the manual process that you were talking about?

Comment: @RitchieRamnial: I meant explicitly in your own code decompress the content. You already found the gzip process, and in my second comment I linked to the deflate procedure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, ive had a good look at the manual deflate code  but i still cant incorporate it into my download code. i would really really appreciate it if you could give me a working example!"

Comment: @RitchieRamnial: see the [`urllib3` source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py#L18-L44) then.