# C# Change Background Color Header

Tags: c#

I have a PNG file in which I want to set / change the background color in its header.

The picture itself should not be edited. 
I'm talking about the header here (https://www.metadata2go.com/file-info/background-color). I don't want to change the pixels.

Tried https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 but don't know how to add a value that doesn't yet exist and how to match it ID is. Also, I'm not at all sure if it's the right approach.

I can't get any further, can you help me?

Comment: See: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16424/Writing-a-Background-Color-bKGD-Chunk-to-a-PNG-Fil and https://stackoverflow.com/q/723392/8967612

Comment: I'm sorry. Of course that was totally correct! Thank you so much! Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ahmed Abdelhameed the solution is https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16424/Writing-a-Background-Color-bKGD-Chunk-to-a-PNG-Fil

Here the Code Source: codeproject !

```
public class BackgroundHeaderChanger
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates a byte array containing the calculated CRC.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buf">The raw data on which to calculate the CRC.</param>
    public static byte[] GetCrc(byte[] buffer)
    {
        uint data = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        int n;

        if (!IsTableCreated)
            CreateCrcTable();

        for (n = 0; n < buffer.Length; n++)
            data = CrcTable[(data ^ buffer[n]) & 0xff] ^ (data >> 8);

        data = data ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;

        byte b1 = Convert.ToByte(data >> 24);
        byte b2 = Convert.ToByte(b1 << 8 ^ data >> 16);
        byte b3 = Convert.ToByte(((data >> 16 << 16) ^ (data >> 8 << 8)) >> 8);
        byte b4 = Convert.ToByte((data >> 8 << 8) ^ data);

        return new byte[] { b1, b2, b3, b4 };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the CRC table for calculating a 32-bit CRC.
    /// </summary>
    private static void CreateCrcTable()
    {
        uint c;
        int k;
        int n;

        for (n = 0; n < 256; n++)
        {
            c = (uint)n;

            for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            {
                if ((c & 1) == 1)
                {
                    c = 0xedb88320 ^ (c >> 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    c = c >> 1;
                }
            }
            CrcTable[n] = c;
        }
        IsTableCreated = true;
    }
    static uint[] CrcTable = new uint[256];
    static bool IsTableCreated = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes a backup background color to the specified PNG file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">The path and name of the PNG file to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="color">The <see cref="Color"/> to set as the backup background color.</param>
    public static void WriteBackupBackgroundColor(string fileName, Color color)
    {
        // Length: 6 bytes, bKGD, then the color
        byte[] lengthData = { 0, 0, 0, 6 };
        byte[] bkgdChunk = { 98, 75, 71, 68, 0, color.R, 0, color.G, 0, color.B };
        byte[] crcData = GetCrc(bkgdChunk);
        byte[] data;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        using (BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            data = binReader.ReadBytes((int)binReader.BaseStream.Length);
        }

        // 18 bytes is the size of a bKGD chunk
        byte[] newData = new byte[data.Length + 18];
        int dataIndex = 0;
        bool wroteChunk = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!wroteChunk && data[i + 4] == 'I' && data[i + 5] == 'D' && data[i + 6] == 'A' && data[i + 7] == 'T')
            {
                Array.Copy(lengthData, 0, newData, dataIndex, 4);
                dataIndex += 4;
                Array.Copy(bkgdChunk, 0, newData, dataIndex, bkgdChunk.Length);                 
                dataIndex += bkgdChunk.Length;
                Array.Copy(crcData, 0, newData, dataIndex, 4);
                dataIndex += 4;

                wroteChunk = true;
            }
            newData[dataIndex++] = data[i];
        }


        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            File.Delete(fileName);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            binWriter.Write(newData);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
 BackgroundHeaderChanger.WriteBackupBackgroundColor(@"C:\TestImg\test.png", Color.Black);
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please note that while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for Info! Changed