# Saving text in iTXt chunk in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, text, png

How can I save text in iTXt png chunk in objective-c?

I have found [a description of the PNG format](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11iTXt), an example [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721918/how-can-i-save-a-png-with-a-text-or-itxt-chunk-from-java) and [in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842387/php-add-itxt-comment-to-a-png-image) but can't figure out how to do it on objective-c.

How saved information can be read?

Comment: Is libpng a solution? Are there any objective-c wrappers for that library?

Comment: You could also try [PngCs](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs) with Monotouch

Answer (score -2):

Well there are several ways to read data from a file in Objective C. In general most of the collection classes have a method similar to the following:

```
+ arrayWithContentsOfFile:
+ arrayWithContentsOfURL:
+ dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
+ dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:
+ stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:
```

Depending on what kind of data is stored in the file you use different methods. The first 4 methods are used when the data saved in the files is in PLIST format. The last one is used to read string from a file.

Note all these methods are class methods (static class function in C++), there are corresponding instance methods(member functions in C++).

Refer iOS/MAC developer library for details:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/

Comment: Mmm... Does it mean that that I should combine bytes manually? Looks like in java example some sort of library was used (PNGMetadata), are there any similar librarys in objective-c?

>Depending on what kind of data is stored in the file you use different methods.
I have PNG file (screenshot) and I want to save text data (custom description of an image).

Answer (score -2):

Also in order to save custom objects in a file your object must conform to NSCoding protocol. See details here:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.

What that means is the your object class must implement:

```
– initWithCoder: 
– encodeWithCoder:
```

Once you have an object which conformas to NSCoding protocol, you can us NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver to read and write data to/from a file. Find references here:

NSKeyedArchiver:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSKeyedUnarchiver:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html